# Complex if statement with CodeDom

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, codedom

I'm wondering how complex if statements represented in c# syntax would translate into CodeDom.  There probably isn't a CodeDom Expression object to represent a grouping (represented as round brackets in c#) as that might be considered potentially language dependant, which CodeDom is not.

So for discussion purposes, f I have a hypothetical complex if statement such as the following (excessive indenting just for readability...)  How do I represent that in a CodeDom expression?

```
if (
            ( 
                (
                    x == 1                  
                    &&              
                    y == 2                  

                    &&                 
                    z == 3                    
                )                           
                ||
                (
                    x == 2                  
                    &&              
                    y == 1                  
                 )                          
            )                               
            ||      
            (
                (
                    A == 1                  
                    ||              
                    A == 3                  
                )                           
                &&
                (
                    B == 2                  
                    ||              
                    B == 5                  
                )                           
            )                               

            &&
            C == 123                          


);//end if
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh I think I realized how this works...
It all boils down to representing each individual comparison with a binary operator expression object.

So essentially I would end up with a series of nested CodeBinaryOperatorExpression objects that are chained together via the left and right code expressions...

```
if ( 
     (
        ( 
            (
                x == 1                  //A
                &&              
                y == 2                  //B
                                        //C == A && B
                &&                 
                y == 3                  //D  
            )                           //E = C && D
            ||
            (
                x == 2                  //F
                &&              
                y == 1                  //G
             )                          //H == F && G
        )                               //I == E || H
        ||      
        (
            (
                A == 1                  //J
                ||              
                A == 3                  //K
            )                           //L = J || K
            &&
            (
                B == 2                  //M
                ||              
                B == 5                  //N
            )                           //O = M || N
        )                               //P = L && O
      )                                 //Q = I || P
      &&
      z = 123                           //R 
                                        //S = Q && R
   ) //end if
```